# Consignment transactions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

Using QBFC, I see that, if I use Sales Receipts, I can specify that funds received are placed into "Undeposited Funds."  The other half of the double entry should be split between Sales:Consignment Sales and Consignor Payable (an AP account).  I don't see any way to specify this part of the transaction.  Sales Orders don't allow me to specify an account at all.  How should these transactions be entered?

Answer (score 0):

Sales Receipts are A/R transactions, *not* A/P transactions. e.g. they are for money coming in, not money going out. Hence why you don't see the A/P side of things.

You should probably ask your accountant how he wants you to enter in the A/P side of the transaction. It will likely be as a Check or Bill + BillPayment.

Sales Orders are non-posting transactions, and thus don't refer to A/R or A/P accounts.

TLDR: Ask your accountant how he wants you to enter A/P transactions.

Comment: As I said above, our clients are consignment shops, so they need to be able to enter part of their sales income as AP.  I am a programmer of consignment software, not a shop owner.

I do know that sales receipts are normally AR transactions.  I need a way to accommodate a slightly different business model.  Can QB do this?

Comment: Yes, QuickBooks can do this. There are about 10 different ways to do this in QuickBooks though. What you're asking isn't a programming question though - *it's an accounting question*. Ask the accountant (or actual business owners) how they want the data entered, and then it should be pretty apparent how to program it.

Comment: The answer is probably - add a corresponding Bill for each Sales Receipt.

Comment: AddBill provides OverRideItemAccountRef.  So I can specify one account.  I need to specify two.  Yes, I am programming this to suit specific customer wishes.

Comment: Add multiple Lines, each referencing their own Item or Account.

Comment: AddBill requires a VendorRef, which means it is meant for adding bills due a supplier.  Most sales receipts involve more than one consignor (vendor), so I suppose I could enter a separate AddBill for each invoice line item.  The important question is, will this function accept a posting to Sales:Consignment Sales, which is not an AP account?

Comment: I see BillAdd must link to a Purchase Order.  That probably won't work for me here

Comment: But maybe the PO link isn't required if I include an ItemRef, even though LinkToTxn is marked as required.  Not sure how absolute "required" is.

Comment: Bills most certainly DO NOT need to link to Purchase Orders. They can if you want them to, but they do NOT need to.

Comment: I see that inventory item records all specification of an income account ref and a COGS account ref.  Sales:Consignor Sales works for the income account, but as I feared, when QB says it wants a COGS account, an AP account won't work (Consignor Payable).  

The Sales Receipt record allows for an OverrideItemAccountRef, but it doesn't say whether it is overriding the income or the COGS account.  

The Bill record you recommend also doesn't say which inventory account it is overriding, but regardless, if QB won't accept an AP account for COGS directly, it probably won't accept it as override?

Comment: You need to use a Bill or other A/P transaction for what you're trying to do. You can't ONLY use a Sales Receipt. That's just not how QuickBooks (or really any accounting platform) works. Sales Receipts are A/R transactions, so they only affect A/R. You need an equivalent A/P transaction too. The Bill will affect any inventory accounts that the Items on the Bill references.

Comment: Using Sales Receipt - $100
    DepositToAccountRef = Undeposited Funds
    Amount = $100
    ORSalesReceiptLineAdd
        Amount=$60

The ItemInventory record has an income account of Sales:Consignment Sales.  I assume that will be used here?

Using Bill
    APAccountRef="Consignor Payable"
    ORLineItemAdd
        Amount = $40

Bills require an APAccountRef, which is fine.  The ItemInventory record requires a COGS account.  I don't want that to be used here.  It might be that the ORLineItemAdd section will accept an AP account, but I don't want a double posting.

Comment: The AP section does not include an amount, so I assume it is totaling the ORLineItemAdd amounts.  How can this work?

Comment: These are accounting questions, not programming questions. Ask your accountant to show you how he wants them entered into QuickBooks. Once you have screenshots of that, it should be blatantly obvious what you need to do in the code. With respect to totals - just like in the QuickBooks GUI, all totals are derived from the sum of the line items.

Comment: I know what I need QB to do.  The question is how to make it happen.  My main concern is that QB requires a COGS account for the ItemInventory record, but I don't want QB to use it.  I need the Bill posting to touch AP account "Consignor Payable", which it looks like it will.  But that is the only action I need from Bill posting.  I need to be able to reference ItemInventory records in ORLineItemAdd section without triggering posting to accounts attached to the ItemInventory record.

I understand that in a normal retail situation, QB defaults would work fine.  But this is for consignments.

Comment: If you ask your accountant, he'll be able to show you how to do this in QuickBooks - then you could just replicate this in QuickBooks.  In any case, inventory items will always affect COGS if a COGS account is selected. If you don't want COGS to be affected, either don't use an inventory item, or don't use the item functionality of the bill at all and instead use account lines.

Comment: Account Lines.  That would be ExpenseLineAddList?  These need to be expense accounts, right?

Dont use an inventory item.  Is there some other item record than ItemInventory?

Comment: ItemService, ItemNonInventory, ItemOtherCharge, etc.

Comment: I am thinking this might work, if QB will accept it:

Using Sales Receipt - $100  
`DepositToAccountRef = Undeposited Funds  
Amount = $100 totaled from SalesRecipts  
ORSalesReceiptLineAdd  
    Two entries with the same ItemRef.ListID:  
        OverrideItemAccountRef =Sales:Consignment Sales  
 Amount=$60  
 OverrideItemAccountRef =ConsignorPayable  
 Amount=$40`  

Using Bill won't work because I need both contra account entries in Sales Receipts ORSalesReceiptLineAdd to give the total deposit to Undeposited Funds.

I would use this with ItemNonInventory.  Have I violated any QB rules?

Answer (score 0):

Sales Receipts use items for the offset against Undeposited Funds. QuickBooks doesn't let you create an Item that links to an A/P account and a regular item can't be split between two income accounts, unless you use group items, but that would get messy for this purpose I think.

I would suggest that you enter the Sales Receipt transaction with the item hitting the Sales:Consignment account for the full amount of the item's price. Then, create a Bill transaction that offsets your Consignor Payable and Sales:Consignment for the amount owed to the consignor.